# Can we integrate the WSO2-BAM with other SOA/BPM vendor products

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

If it is possible, do we need to write any plugins?
I wanted to know if there is any use case around TIBCO BE or EMS integration with WSO2-BAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways if you want to publish data to WSO2 BAM.

1. You can write a Data Agent which resides in your preferred other-vendor-product which pushes data to BAM. Refer http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM230/Data+Publisher
2. Publish data via Thrift to BAM. Here the preferred other-vendor-product is language independent as no need to use Java.
3. Publish data to BAM via REST API. Example is given in http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM230/Sending+Events+through+the+REST+API

Answer (score 1):

You can.You have to write plugins for that..main components would be;
Data agents :to publish data
Data receiver/analyzer/dashboards..:To view analyze data, You can install as an archive(toolbox).You can find detail info [here](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM230/WSO2+Business+Activity+Monitor+Documentation)

Answer (score 0):

Need to write custom data publisher. [Custom Data Publisher](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/CEP210/Custom+Data+Publishers) section from the BAM documentation shows how to do this. Also, if you download BAM, unzip and go to <BAM_HOME>/samples there you'll find samples which involve sending bunch of events to BAM to show its functionality. One such example can be found in <BAM_HOME>/samples/httpd-logs/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/bam/httpdlogs/sample/HttpdLogAgent.java